# uninstall a package in DELPHI XE2

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe2

I want to uninstall a package from the DELPHI XE2 Servicepack 4 and replace it with a new one.
Under package -> INSTALL PACKAGE -> UNINSTALL PACKAGE BUTTON, is this simple flow already enough or do I need to make additional actions to avoid any other problems.

On my case I need to uninstall INDY 10 and install the latest SVN version to my system

Answer (score 1):

You should also check your library path and remove and folders that explicitly refer to the package that you just uninstalled.

Comment: found http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.DE.aspx, will try to work with these instructions and report again